# Hint in hangman game

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to put hint in output like this >>

1. --e - - ca
2. p--i--a-

how can i?

```
import random

word_list = ["india", "pakistan", "america"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

word_length = len(chosen_word)

display = []

for _ in range (word_length):
    letter = chosen_word[_]
    display += '_' 
print(display) 

lives = 8
game_over = False
while not game_over:
    guess = input("enter a guess:").lower()
    
    for position in range(word_length):
       
        random.choice(display[position])
        
        letter = chosen_word[position]
         
        if letter == guess:
            display[position] = letter
    if guess not in chosen_word:
        lives -= 1
    if lives == 0:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want your hint to contain 3 letters and the letters should be random, you could do:

```
hint = ["-"]*word_length

# Gets 3 random positions to have for the letters
positions = random.sample(range(0,word_length), 3)

# At those positions, change the "-" in hint to a letter.
for i in positions:
  hint[i] = chosen_word[i]

hint = "".join(hint)
print(hint)
```